# Does the Cessna 152 have a name?

Tags: cessna-152, aircraft-naming

I'm wondering if the Cessna 152 has a name? There's the Cessna Skyhawk 172 and the Cessna Skylane 182.

Comment: Related: [Is there a reason or code behind the Cessna model numbers?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46967/14897)

Comment: Informally, "Skychicken"

Answer (score 2):

Cessna started to apply marketing names to their line in the early 60s (along with goofy marketing gimmicks like the "Land-O-matic" name for the spring steel gear).  Up to then they were just known by model numbers.  The 150 was the "Commuter". For some reason the name wasn't applied to the 152 (which is a 150 with a Lycoming engine), which just has the model number.

Comment: But there was a variant called the 152 Aerobat, but in this case the name was to distinguish it from the basic 152.

Comment: Aerobat was also for the 150, when the aerobatic model came out in 1970. Why they kept the marketing name only for the aerobatic version when the Lyc engine was done to create the 152 is a mystery.

Comment: Originally, only C172s with the deluxe option package were "Skyhawks"; the base models weren't.  They got rid of the base model in 1976, so only Skyhawks (and the new Skyhawk II, with a *more deluxe* option package) remained.  Likewise, the C182A was technically the first Skylane because the original C182 (no letter) wasn't called that.  TL;DR: Cessna naming is a mess.

Comment: The 152 with the 125 hp engine modification is known as the Sparrow Hawk. Although, I'm not sure if that is an official name given by Cessna.

Comment: No that's an STC name.